# Task scheduler creates corrupted version of generated by script file

Tags: file, powershell, task, schedule

I've been working on a little project in Powershell.
My task was to create a script that will collect all files from mail attachments, merge all .pdf files into one and send the generated file to my email.
The script works completely fine in Powershell ISE, but when I try to run it from task scheduler, the merged .pdf file is corrupted without any data in it.
Keep in mind I am new to this stuff.

This is my main code that does all the heavy work:

```
    function getAttachments
    {
    #########################################################
    ##-----------------------------------------------------## 
    ##                GET ATTACHMENTS                      ## 
    ##-----------------------------------------------------## 
    #########################################################

    ##PATH TO CREDENTIAL
    $credpath = "C:\Users\" + $env:UserName + "\Documents\myCred_${env:USERNAME}_${env:COMPUTERNAME}.xml"

    #test variable
    $test = Test-Path $credpath

    ##TEST IF CREDENTIAL EXISTS
    if(!$test){
    ## USER PROMPT PSW  CREDENTIAL ## 
        $cred = Get-Credential 

        #save credential in documents
        $cred | Export-CliXml -Path $credpath
    }else{
    ##READ USER CREDENTIAL FROM FILE
        $cred = Import-CliXml -Path $credpath
    }

    ##url and date variables
    $url = "https://outlook.office365.com/api/v1.0/me/messages" 

    $d = [DateTime]::Today.AddDays(-1)
    $global:date = $d.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")

    ## Get all messages that have attachments where received date is greater than $date  
    $messageQuery = "" + $url + "?`$select=Id&`$filter=HasAttachments eq true and DateTimeReceived ge " + $date 
    $messages = Invoke-RestMethod $messageQuery -Credential $cred 

    ## Loop through each results 
    foreach ($message in $messages.value) 
    { 
        # get attachments and save to file system 
        $query = $url + "/" + $message.Id + "/attachments" 
        $attachments = Invoke-RestMethod $query -Credential $cred 

        # in case of multiple attachments in email 
        foreach ($attachment in $attachments.value) 
        { 
            Write-Host “Found File :- ” $attachment.Name
            $path = "c:\Attachments\" + $attachment.Name 

            $Content = [System.Convert]::FromBase64String($attachment.ContentBytes) 
            Set-Content -Path $path -Value $Content -Encoding Byte 
        } 
    } 
}

    function sendAttachments
    {
    #############################################################
    ##---------------------------------------------------------##
    ##          SEND ATTACHMENTS AND DELETE FILES              ##
    ##---------------------------------------------------------##
    #############################################################

    #Connection Details

    #PATH TO CREDENTIAL
    $credpath = "C:\Users\" + $env:UserName + "\Documents\myCred_${env:USERNAME}_${env:COMPUTERNAME}.xml"
    $cred = Import-CliXml -Path $credpath

    $smtpServer = “ smtp.office365.com”

    $msg = new-object Net.Mail.MailMessage 

    #Change port number for SSL to 587
    $smtp = New-Object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($SmtpServer, 25) 

    #Uncomment Next line for SSL  
    $smtp.EnableSsl = $true

    $smtp.Credentials = $cred

    $msg.IsBodyHtml = $true

    #From Address
    $msg.From = $cred.UserName
    #To Address, Copy the below line for multiple recipients
    $msg.To.Add(“email@gmail.com”)

    #Message Body
    $msg.Body=”<h2>Alle attachments samen bevinden zich in de bijlage van did email</h2> <br/><br/>”

    #Message Subject
    $msg.Subject = “no-reply: Email met alle attachments”

    #your file location
    $files=Get-ChildItem “C:\Attachments\”

    #attach the right file
    $file = $global:pname
    Write-Host “Attaching File :- ” $file
    $attachment = New-Object System.Net.Mail.Attachment –ArgumentList C:\Attachments\$file
    $msg.Attachments.Add($attachment)

    #send email
    $smtp.Send($msg)
    $attachment.Dispose();
    $msg.Dispose();

    #delete the files from the folder
    Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Attachments -Include * -File -Recurse | foreach { $_.Delete()}
     }

function mergePDF
{
#############################################################
##---------------------------------------------------------##
##                MERGE ALL PDF FILES                      ##
##---------------------------------------------------------##
#############################################################
    $workingDirectory = "C:\Attachments"
    $itspath = $PSScriptRoot
    $global:pname = $global:date + "_pdfAttachments.pdf"
    $pdfs = ls $workingDirectory -recurse | where {-not $_.PSIsContainer -and $_.Extension -imatch "^\.pdf$"};

    [void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom([System.IO.Path]::Combine($itspath, 'itextsharp.dll'));

    $output = [System.IO.Path]::Combine($workingDirectory, $pname);
    $fileStream = New-Object System.IO.FileStream($output, [System.IO.FileMode]::OpenOrCreate);
    $document = New-Object iTextSharp.text.Document;
    $pdfCopy = New-Object iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfCopy($document, $fileStream);
    $document.Open();

    foreach ($pdf in $pdfs) {
        $reader = New-Object iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader($pdf.FullName);
        [iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader]::unethicalreading = $true
        $pdfCopy.AddDocument($reader);
        $reader.Dispose();
    }
    $document.Close()
    $pdfCopy.Dispose();
    $document.Dispose();
    $fileStream.Dispose();
}
getAttachments
Start-Sleep -s 10
mergePDF
Start-Sleep -s 10
sendAttachments
```

In this piece of code that I run in another script file, I create a new task:

```
#############################################################
##---------------------------------------------------------##
##          SCHEDULE SCRIPTS IN WINDOWS TASKS              ##
##---------------------------------------------------------##
#############################################################

##PATH TO CREDENTIAL
$credpath = "C:\Users\" + $env:UserName + "\Documents\myCred_${env:USERNAME}_${env:COMPUTERNAME}.xml"

#test variable
$test = Test-Path $credpath

##TEST IF CREDENTIAL EXISTS
if(!$test){
## USER PROMPT PSW  CREDENTIAL ## 
    $cred = Get-Credential

    #save credential in documents
    $cred | Export-CliXml -Path $credpath
}

$taskName = "ManageEmailAttachments"
$taskExists = Get-ScheduledTask | Where-Object {$_.TaskName -like $taskName }

if($taskExists) 
{
   Get-ScheduledJob ManageEmailAttachments
   Unregister-ScheduledJob ManageEmailAttachments
   $wshell = New-Object -ComObject Wscript.Shell
   $wshell.Popup("Task successfully deleted, run the script again to schedule the task",0,"Done",0x0)
} 
else 
{
    $tt = Get-Date
    $tt = $tt.AddMinutes(1)
    $testtime = $tt.ToString("HH:mm:ss")

    #set trigger
    $trigger = New-JobTrigger -Daily -At "1:00"
    $testtrigger = New-JobTrigger -Daily -At $testtime

    #path to the scripts
    $scriptPath = $PSScriptRoot + "\wps_manage_pdf_attachments.ps1"


    #options(optional)
    $option = New-ScheduledJobOption -WakeToRun: $true

    #create a new task
    Register-ScheduledJob -Name ManageEmailAttachments -FilePath $scriptPath -Trigger  $testtrigger -ScheduledJobOption $option 
}
```

The script when run in Powershell works great, it gets all the attachments from mailbox, merges them into 1 .pdf file and sends them to the requested email address. But when scheduled in windows task scheduler it does the first step fine, but when merged, the .pdf file is corrupted without any content.

I couldn't figure out how to make it work so I posted a question on the forum.
Hope you guys find a way to figure it out.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the problem nested itself in the main code. I used:

```
Try{...} 
Catch{$_ | Out-File C:\errors.txt}
```

In mergePDF function to find out what the error was. Seems like the path to my ITextSharp.dll was incorrect. $PSScriptRoot that I used showed "C:\windows\windows32" instead of where the script actually is.

So what I did instead was add a line in my batch file to copy the itextsharp.dll to %Temp%:

```
xcopy Scripts\itextsharp.dll %Temp% /D >NUL 2>NUL
```

and then read the file from there with:

```
$itsPath = [System.IO.Path]::GetTempPath()
```

And everything works as it should be. I know this isn't the best way to do it but I had this batch file before to make the script run by just dubbleclicking it.
So adding a little line won't hurt.

I hope this helps anyone with the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use below function to get script root directory.
    Function Get-ScriptDirectory
    {
     $Invocation = (Get-Variable MyInvocation -scope 1).Value
     Split-path $Invocation.MyCommand.Path
    }
    $scriptPath=Join-Path(Get-ScriptDirectory) 'wps_manage_pdf_attachments.ps1'

Comment: Thanks for improving my code but this doesn't solve the problem. The pdf file generated is still without any content